# operation of permutation elements

Tags: group-theory

I would like to permute the elements of the set $A$ using symmetric group. How may I be able to do that? For example, in `Sage`,

```
G = SymmetricGroup(3)
for i in G: print [j*i*j^(-1) for j in G]
```

gives all the conjugacy classes for $S_3$ group. How may I able to do same with `SymmetricGroup[3]` is Mathematica.

Furthermore, I would like find the elements of $S_3$ that leaves the set $A=\{1, 2\}$ invariant or leaves each element fixed. How may I be able to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the OP questions somewhat unclear. In any case, the answers can be found in the tutorials ["Permutations"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Permutations.html) and 
["Permutation Groups"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PermutationGroups.html).

> I would like to permute the elements of the set A using symmetric
>   group.

```
In[44]:= Permute[{1,2,3},SymmetricGroup[3]]

Out[44]= {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}
```

The Mathematica equivalent of the Sage code:

```
G = SymmetricGroup(3)
for i in G: print [j*i*j^(-1) for j in G]
```

should be written with other operators/functions, otherwise `j*i*j^(-1)` will simplify to `i`. Here I use `NonCommutativeMultiply` and `Inverse`:

```
In[42]:= Permute[NonCommutativeMultiply[j, i, Inverse[j]], SymmetricGroup[3]]

Out[42]= {j ** i ** Inverse[j], j ** Inverse[j] ** i, 
 i ** j ** Inverse[j], i ** Inverse[j] ** j, Inverse[j] ** j ** i, 
 Inverse[j] ** i ** j}
```

> Furthermore, I would like find the elements of $S_3$  that leaves the
>   set $A=\{1,2\}$ invariant [...]

This is unclear to me because:

```
In[47]:= GroupStabilizer[SymmetricGroup[3], {1, 2}]

Out[47]= PermutationGroup[{}]
```

hence

```
In[36]:= Permute[{1,2,3}, GroupStabilizer[SymmetricGroup[3], {1, 2}]]

Out[36]= {{}}
```

May be the following examples are helpful illustrations.

Fixing the 3d element using $S_3$:

```
In[50]:= Permute[Range[3], GroupStabilizer[SymmetricGroup[3], {3}]]

Out[50]= {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 3}}
```

Fixing the elements `{1,2}` using $S_4$:

```
In[49]:= Permute[Range[4], GroupStabilizer[SymmetricGroup[4], {1, 2}]]

Out[49]= {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}}
```